# Does it make sense to track compiled CoffeeScript and SASS files in version control?

Tags: version-control, coffeescript, sass, gruntjs

I'm building a single page web app and prefer to write my source code in CoffeeScript and SASS. I use Grunt to dynamically compile my source at run time to test in the browser (using grunt-contrib-watch, livereload, etc.).

When I'm ready to create a release of my app, I run a Grunt build script which compiles the source again, generates documentation, bumps the version number, and so on. I don't make any changes ever to my compiled source because the build script freshly recompiles every time (and obviously overwrites any changes to the compiled source).

**My question is: does it make sense to check the compiled source into version control? If so, what's the rationale behind that?**

A few more observations specific to my scenario:

1. The source is always checked into version control.
2. The compiled source can be rebuilt from the source at any time.
3. I have a separate "dist" directory in which a compiled and ready-to-deploy version of the app is kept at all times--and this is tracked in version control.

Comment: There are lots of opinions here. But in general I feel that if you provide a way to produce a distribution (grunt in your case), then no, I do not like to commit those files. If, on the other hand, you do not provide a method for compilation, then sure, commit a distributable file. In your case, I wouldn't do it. (And I'm not making this an answer, because all you can hope for here is an opinion.)

Comment: @jakerella I had a similar train of thought, but it thought it would be worth reaching out to see if there are any reasons I'm overlooking. While your comment is certainly an opinion, it still answers the question. I'm new to the SO community in terms of contributing, but it seems to me as if it would certainly qualify as an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would be analogous as versioning a compiled binary from a C codebase.

You seem to have answered your own question.

If

> The source is always checked into version control.

and

> The compiled source can be rebuilt from the source at any time.

then **no, you should not version built files**.

Your continuous deployment process should be able test your sources and compile them into a distributable format without interference.

Comment: Is it best practice to over soon control the distributable version? Or is it better to leave that solely to the CI process in the way you described in your answer?

Comment: The reason some people commit built files to a `dist` folder is to allow others to download them via package managers like bower. However, if you are publishing to a package repository (where your built files are stored, like npm) then theres no need to version them.